# How do I safely check if an object has a property or a method?

Tags: javascript

`.hasOwnProperty()` doesn't check for inherited members, and `in` operator doesn't work for all types of objects (e.g. strings and `null`)

Solutions using libraries (especially Lodash.js) are welcome as well.

---

I'm writing a function, which tries to figure out if an object is array-like (including strings). I can't directly check with `.hasOwnProperty()` because properties can be inherited:

```
function isArrayLike(val) {
    return 'length' in Object(val)
}
```

Another example:

```
function stringify(val) {
    if ('toJSON' in Object(val))
        return JSON.stringify(val.toJSON())
    else
        return JSON.stringify(val)
}
```

so (`'toJSON' in Object(val)` doesn't break if an argument is a primitive)

---

`prop in Object(val)` seems working great

Comment: Strings and `null` are not objects, they are primitive values. It seems the value your testing the existence on is not always an object then. Can you provide more context? What is the possible input?

Comment: Is there some reason why `if (foo&&foo.bar)` won't work for you?

Comment: @CrayonViolent—not if *foo.bar* is falsey, say null, undefined or 0.

Comment: erm.. yeah I suppose so.. for some reason my brain just assumed.. doh.

Comment: Can include example of application at Question ?

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. What is it that you're attempting to do?

Comment: @GabrielLebec Don't get confused by [`typeof`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3). [`null`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.11) is a [primitive value](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.2), and is the only member of the [Null type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.12).

Comment: @Oriol I stand corrected!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Effectively, the [`in` operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.7) only works on objects:

> If Type(*rval*) is not Object, throw a **TypeError** exception.

Therefore, just check that it really is an object:

```js
obj === Object(obj) // Filter out non-objects
&& prop in obj      // Check property
```

Note that booleans, numbers, strings and symbols are primitive values, so they have no properties. However, it might seem the opposite, e.g. `"string".valueOf`. That works because, under the hood, a string object is created, and that object inherits the `valueOf` property from `String.prototype`.

If you want to test this, you can use

```
obj != null            // Filter out undefined and null
&& prop in Object(obj) // Convert to object and check property
```

Comment: How do I check if a string has a `valueOf`?

Comment: @Nieralyte Strings don't have a `valueOf` property. However, if you attempt to access it, a new string object will be created, and that object has that property.

Comment: Note that host objects can return [anything they like](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3) other "undefined", "boolean", "number", or "string" (and must return "function" if they implement `[[Call]]`), and that *functions* are objects too, so it may be better to test if `typeof obj` is not in the above list rather than returns *object*. E.g. in IE ActiveX objects used to return "unknown", and DOM objects might return say "HTMLParagraphElement".

Comment: @RobG Good point, I edited it. However, I dislike that it may be not much forwards compatible, e.g. ES6 also introduces the Symbol type.

Comment: @Oriol—yes, designing things to be "general purpose" is difficult in a changing environment. Better if the OP puts some boundaries on the question and limits it to certain types or use cases. Of course there's always *try..catch*…

Comment: I think `obj === Object(obj)` should also work. `Object` will convert to an object, and the `===` will ensure that `obj` is the same object.